# Kendo-UI nested vertical menu via JSON

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui

My problem is that i can't parse my JSON for creating cascade vertical menu.

Here is an example what i wanted to do:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwsey.png

```
JSFillde with the problem:    
http://jsfiddle.net/a05bqu2o/2/
```

Actually i need to create category-subcategory-subsubcategories for my project. 
So the question is: Why the first "initSource" in js fiddle doesn't work? Is it because of invalid JSON?

I just need an examples of category system in Kendo UI (with KendoUI routing). I want to create menu of it via JSON.

I need to load and render my vertical menu on first time initialization.
(I must use HierarchicalDataSource ?)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems:

1. For creating a menu I think that you should use a `HierarchicalDataSource` and not a `DataSource`. `DataSources` do not have *nesting*.
2. There is a spelling error, it is `schema` and not `scheme`.
3. And the most important, `data` needs to be an `array` and not an `object`.